# Else statement in PHP code not processing

Tags: php

my IF statements in this code are working, but the ELSE statement NEVER processes...and I am not sure why....in fact all of the code processes up until the ELSE statement, and the captua works properly too, if the captcha is right, the user gets a positive message and the data is posted to the database.  If the  captcha is wrong, no information is posted, but no message is given either..please help:

```
if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))
    if($_SESSION["captcha"] == strtolower($_POST["captcha"]))
        if(mysql_query($sql)) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully, The records manager will provide you with your record within 3 days!')</script>";
            //mail('joe.blow@idaho.com', 'SRRS - New Records Await Processing', 'SRRS - There are new records for processing in the SRRS System' );
            //$to  = 'joe.blow2@idaho.com' . ', ';
            //$to .= $email;
            $to = "joe.blow3@idaho.com";
            $subject = "SRRS NOTIFICATION - New Student Record Await Processing";
            $message = "New Student Record Requests have been submitted and Await Processing";
            $from = "joe.blow@idaho.com";
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('An Email Has to sent from the SRRS Records Management System to the Records Management Administrator for Processing.')</script>";
             //Mail the user
                        $to = $email;
            $subject = "SRRS NOTIFICATION - Your new record request has been submitted.";
            $message = "SRRS - Your new record request for $givenname, $legname has been submitted, It will be procssed within 3 working days";
            $from = "joe.blow@idaho.com";
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Human Verification not entered properly!')</script>";
        }
```

Comment: Please share your code **here**

Comment: Your first if statements don't even have brackets...

Comment: Please read this for information of how to write a good question for SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Bankzilla control structures don't need brackets. They will include the next line after them in their scope, and in this case they are nested one by one until the deepest one which **does** have brackets, so executed multiple commands. It's horrible for readability, sure, but [there's nothing wrong with it](https://eval.in/178256).

Comment: Also after looking at code, it's not even all there. Where is `$sql` defined?

Comment: Sorry Bankzilla, I didi not post all of the code, because I felt the problem lied within my IF and ELSE statement, and so provided that peice of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your output for "human verification" being incorrect is the else statement for your **SQL query** rather than the if statement before that which does the captcha comparison.

Condensed version of what you're doing:

```
if(isset($_POST["captcha"]))
    if($_SESSION["captcha"] == strtolower($_POST["captcha"]))
        if(mysql_query($sql)) {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // output CAPTCHA ERROR! <-- wrong place
        }
```

Change where your statement is:

```
if(isset($_POST["captcha"])) {
    if($_SESSION["captcha"] == strtolower($_POST["captcha"])) {
        if(mysql_query($sql)) {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // CAPTCHA was fine, but the SQL query failed.
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Human Verification not entered properly!')</script>";
    }
}
```

**Note:** While using curly brackets for control structures are not necessary when you only have one statement following it (an if block counts as one statement), it's far better for readability if you include them (so I've added them for you).

**Looking forward:** there are better ways to write your code than lots of nested if statements. You should try working on a structure that catches and handles errors as they happen, instead of wrapping large blocks of code in if statements and dealing with the alternative at the end. Try something like this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['captcha']) || $_SESSION['captcha'] != strtolower($_POST['captcha'])) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Human Verification not entered properly!')</script>";
    exit; // kill the rest of the execution
}

if(!mysql_query($sql)) {
    // SQL query failed, output an error
    exit; // kill the rest of the execution
}

// Everything's fine, do the rest of your stuff here.
```

This could be further optimised by using functions and returning false instead of `exit` from various levels of functions that you call whenever you find an error.

Lastly, I'd suggest that outputting Javascript like that with an alert is probably not the best way to be doing this. You should have a kind of structure where the script/function that performs the task returns a boolean result (true/false) representing whether everything has gone smoothly, perhaps with an accompanying error message to describe it, and you should have a separate script/function that deals with the **presentation** of that result. An simple example here would be setting the result and message to the session and redirecting the user with PHP to a page that presents the results, instead of using a script tag with an alert.

While I'm at it too - [`mysql_*` functions are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Comment: Thank-you everyone!!!  I will test this tommorrow, I am confident it will work...sadly I did have a redirect to a new page with an error message with recaptcha, but the user said it was too hard to read, so I changed it to this..I do however agree with you ....A redirect, to an well crafted page would be MUCH better...and I think I'm going to go back to that.  Thank-you scrowler!!!

Comment: scrowler, it works perfectly, I have marked it as the resolution.  As well, I have taken ALL of your advice, and I have also used a redirect with a clear nicely formatted message when the submission is successful!  Thanks!